# Is the following function a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix variable and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$ is a constant matrix. Is the following function is a convex function with respect to $X$:
$$f(X) = \|\max_{j}AX-\min_{j}AX\|_{2},$$
where $\max_{j}$ results in a column vector, each element of which is the maximum of the corresponding row, $\min_{j}$  also results in a column vector, each element of which is the minimum of the corresponding row, $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ denotes the Euclidean norm of a vector.

Comment: Hint: $\max(s, t) - \min(s, t) = \max(s, t) + \max(-s, -t) \ge 0$ is convex on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: It is indeed convex. The standard composition rules (from [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)) don't _quite_ work, because the norm is non-monotonic. But @user251257's hint helps, because the norm *is* monotonic on the nonnegative orthant.